# How to render a react template?

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a web app that serves the user unique pages with a substantial amount of JSX e.g.

```
<Explanation>
<p>Here will be a lengthy section explaining how to solve a problem that I want rendered using the explanation component</p>
<Quote>It might also have child components in it</Quote>
</Explanation> 
<Questions>Here will be some questions I've written</Questions>
<Image> Here will be an image that I want to render using my image component</Image>
```

Ideally I would like to store the JSX in a mongo database as an object like this:

```
post = {
_id: 1,
content: `<Explanation>
<p>Here will be a lengthy section explaining how to solve a problem that I want rendered using the explanation component</p>
<Quote>It might also have child components in it</Quote>
</Explanation> 
<Questions>Here will be some questions I've written</Questions>
<Image> Here will be an image that I want to render using my image component</Image>`
```

because I will have many hundreds of such pages and the user should receive only a particular page.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

At the moment I have resigned to writing an object like this:

```
post = {
_id,
content: [
{component: Explanation, 
props: {key: 'bla'},
content: [
   {component: p,
    props: null,
    content: 'Here will be a lengthy section explaining how to solve a problem that I want rendered using the explanation component'
   }
   ]
}
]
```

and then writing a function that turns them into React elements like so:

```
const renderPost = (post) => {
const JSX = post.content.map(c =>
    React.createElement(c.component, c.props, c.content)
)
return JSX
}
```

but this whole process feels cumbersome and inefficient.

Is there a better way of trying to achieve my goal?

Comment: also try to google this search-terms : `react dynamic render component` results like this seems similar: https://www.storyblok.com/tp/react-dynamic-component-from-json

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick work around.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

var str = `
<Explanation>
  <p>this is ex1 p tag</p>
  <Quote>this is quote</Quote>
</Explanation>
<Questions>This is q</Questions>
<Image>this is img</Image>
`;
const createMarkup = (props) => ({ __html: props });

const Custom = ({ children }) => {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(children)} />;
};
const Quote = ({ children }) => {
  return <blockquote dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(children)} />;
};
const Questions = ({ children }) => {
  return <q dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(children)} />;
};
const Image = ({ children }) => {
  return <h1 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(children)} />;
};
const Explanation = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className="explain" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(children)} />
  );
};

const cpmponentToShow = [];
const components = {
  Custom,
  Explanation,
  Image,
  Questions,
  Quote
};
const componetCreate = (string) => {
  const tags = string.match(/(?<=<)((\w|\b)+)[^>]/g);
  if (tags.length) {
    tags.map((tag) => {
      var regexNew = `<${tag}>([\\s\\S]*?)</${tag}>`;
      var matched = string.match(regexNew);
      const leftOver = matched[1].match(/(?<=<)(\w+)[^>]/g);
      if (!leftOver) {
        cpmponentToShow.push(
          React.createElement(
            components[tag] ? components[tag] : tag,
            null,
            matched[1]
          )
        );
      }
      return null;
    });
  }
};
componetCreate(str);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {cpmponentToShow.map((item, index) => (
        <React.Fragment key={index}>{item}</React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
p {
  color: red;
}
blockquote {
  color: black;
}
q {
  color: purple;
}
h1 {
  color: royalblue;
}
.explain {
  color: salmon;
}
```

[sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-banach-lrety)